# JavaScript variable not in scope

Tags: javascript, playframework

I am trying to write a JavaScript function which simply changes page when a date picker is closed using the Play framework. I've run into an issue where the variable I am using (dateEntry) just doesn't seem to be in scope. The method below works fine when I pass in a string but not when I try and pass in dateEntry which should get the value from the datePicker. I've never used the Play framework before so I assume I am doing something wrong with that. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
            function moveToPlaylistPage() {
                var dateEntry = document.getElementById("dob").value;
                window.location.href = "@routes.PlaylistTableController.playlistTable(dateEntry)"
            }

            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                const options = {
                    autoClose: true,
                    minDate: new Date(1954, 1, 1),
                    maxDate: new Date(2019, 12, 31),
                    yearRange: 70,
                    onClose: moveToPlaylistPage
                };
                const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.datepicker');
                const instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The route string is being passed literally into the `href` property, which is why passing in a string value works, but not the variable name. What you want to do is turn the value of the variable into a string and pass that. Something like:

```
function moveToPlaylistPage() {
    var dateEntry = document.getElementById("dob").value;
    window.location.href = "@routes.PlaylistTableController.playlistTable(" + dateEntry + ")"
}
```

will work fine if you do need IE support, but if you can, I prefer the [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) syntax:

```
function moveToPlaylistPage() {
    var dateEntry = document.getElementById("dob").value;
    window.location.href = `@routes.PlaylistTableController.playlistTable(${dateEntry})`
}
```

[Here is the compatibility matrix for template literal syntax.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=template-literals)